# Superscrollorame Play Sound when reached a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to accomplish that a soundfile will be triggered every time the user scrolls to a certain div.

I tried to accomplish that with superscrollorama and even waypoints, but the sound file get played at pageload only.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here are my codelines (broken down to basics)

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="trewrapper">
    <div id="tretest"></div>
    <div id="tretestsound"></div>
    <div id="tre_pin-frame-unpin" class=""></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #trewrapper {
    margin-right:60px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    min-height: 2500px;
}


#tretest {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1500px;
}

#tretestsound {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0FC;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1900px;
}

#tre_pin-frame-unpin {
     top:100%; 
}
```

**JS:**

```
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://mc-communicate.com/DEV/images/trelock/Trelock_Heartbeat.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
        }, true);

var controller = $.superscrollorama({
            triggerAtCenter: false
        });
            // set duration, in pixels scrolled, for pinned element
                var pinDur = 2800;

                // create animation timeline for pinned element
                var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();
                pinAnimations
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#tretest'), 5, {css:{top: 0}})
                        ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#tretestsound'), 2,{css:{top: 0}}, audioElement.play())
                        ])
                    .append(TweenMax.to($('#tre_pin-frame-unpin'), .5, {css:{top:'100px'}}));

                // pin element, use onPin and onUnpin to adjust the height of the element
                controller.pin($('#trewrapper'), pinDur, {
                    anim:pinAnimations, 
                    onPin: function() {
                        $('#trewrapper').css('height','100%');
                    }, 
                    onUnpin: function() {
                        $('#trewrapper').css('height','900px');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - finally.

I just called an onComplete function after the scrolling element before the one where the animation begins.

```
TweenMax.to($('#tre_schloss'), 5, {css:{opacity: 1},
    onComplete: function(){
         $(function() {                                         
           audioElement.play();
     })
```

So easy ;)